# How to use transactions in DotNetNuke?

Tags: transactions, transactionscope, dotnetnuke

I'm trying to do the most simple thing and apply a transaction to the `CreatePortal` method.

If I'm using `TransactionScope` - It promotes to DTC for some unknown reason - BAD.

```
using (var ts = new TransactionScope())
{
    var portalController = new PortalController();

    var portalId =
        portalController.CreatePortal(
                    "TESTTESTTEST",
                    string.Empty,
                    string.Empty,
                    "TESTTESTTEST_" + new Random().Next(999999),
                    UserController.GeneratePassword(),
                    "TESTTESTTEST_" + new Random().Next(999999) + "@something.com",
                    string.Empty,
                    string.Empty,
                    Globals.ApplicationMapPath + "/Portals/_default/",
                    "Default Website.template",
                    "Portals/TESTTEST",
                    "TESTTESTTEST",
                    string.Empty,
                    string.Empty,
                    false);

    ts.Complete();
}
```

If I'm using `DataProvider.Instance().GetTransaction` and performs `RollbackTransaction` at the end - IT DOES NOT ROLLBACK, which means that the transaction didn't even work.

```
var t = Data.DataProvider.Instance().GetTransaction();

var portalController = new PortalController();

var portalId =
    portalController.CreatePortal(
                "TESTTESTTEST",
                string.Empty,
                string.Empty,
                "TESTTESTTEST_" + new Random().Next(999999),
                UserController.GeneratePassword(),
                "TESTTESTTEST_" + new Random().Next(999999) + "@something.com",
                string.Empty,
                string.Empty,
                Globals.ApplicationMapPath + "/Portals/_default/",
                "Default Website.template",
                "Portals/TESTTEST",
                "TESTTESTTEST",
                string.Empty,
                string.Empty,
                false);

Data.DataProvider.Instance().RollbackTransaction(t);
```

So, How to use transactions in DotNetNuke?

Comment: have you considered putting the transaction login inside the stored procedure itself?

Comment: I don't think that meddling with DNN SP is the smart thing to do. I'm sure there is another legit solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a transaction through the `GetTransaction` method, the `DataProvider` just creates a new connection and gives you the transaction.  You would then need to manually use that transaction to perform whatever action you're going to take against the database.  There isn't a way to pass that transaction so that it gets used by, for example, `CreatePortal`, or any other built-in DNN function.  That functionality appears to be just for any additional database access you might make.

In terms of how to wrap a call from the DNN core in a transaction, I don't think you can.  The cleanest solution I know to recommend (which, unfortunately, still isn't very clean) is to manually call the stored procedure, using a transaction, rather than going through the controller class.

What's your use case, maybe I can recommend a solution that solves the problem some other way...

Comment: My main problem is using DNN entities and my LINQ entities inside a single transaction. The problem shown above is just an obstacle toward the solution of my bigger problem.

Comment: Anyway, how come DNN 5.X does not support `TransactionScope`?!

Comment: @Eran - I think transaction scope just wasnt conceved of at the time dnn was first built  - I for one would love to see DNN support transaction scope but i imagine that its a matter of manpower on the part of the core team  to get it into a future version - of course you could always write your own data provider and support it that way - we sort of did in a strange way

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use Transactions in DNN with the help of [this article](http://woaychee.wordpress.com/2008/12/04/handling-transactions-in-dotnetnuke-custom-module/).

It doesn't apply to your case, but will help others trying to leverage transactions in DNN.